# Are you a LARPer?

Tags: discussion, larp

Asked in respect to [Are we including LARPs?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165/are-we-including-larps). If there are LARPers in the community, I think we should accommodate them and see - while we're in beta - whether the scope of this site can/should include LARP.

So if you're a LARPer, shout out!

### Edit

Editing to bump up the list, now that we are no longer in private beta.

Answer (score 9):

I am. And I think that live-action roleplaying games *are* roleplaying games, and so included in the scope of this site.

Comment: +1 rather than another answer.

Answer (score 5):

I am not, but I think both communities have both a lot in common and a lot to learn from one another. A little cross-pollination is all to the good.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. And I've stated elsewhere there are a lot of very specific implementation/design questions that could benefit from the voting methodology of stack exchange.

Comment: Link to your statements?

Answer (score 2):

I've LARPed in the past but it's been a few years. Still, I like the idea of LARP-related questions here, because it'll give a glimpse into what's currently going on in that area, and while I'm now out of the loop on rules and such, I might have suggestions based on my experiences as to how they should be run, what to bring to one, how to prep for an overnighter, what to expect in general, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If it gets us more questions then I'm all for it at the moment, usually very dry on the ground during GMT waking hours.

Answer (score 1):

I've larped, but am not currently larping. It should be on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Larper and Tabletopper too. Usually I like to be a D&D DungeonMaster =D.