# Are questions about escape games on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic, larp

Does this website accept questions about "real-life" role-playing games?

In my case, I have questions about "escape games", where you are usually trapped in a room and you have one hour to solve a number of puzzles and escape the room.

Comment: Depending on the type of question, you may be able to ask over at [puzzling](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com) as long as it fits their [guidelines](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

We accept questions about LARPs (live action roleplaying games), as discussed in [Are questions about LARPs on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165/are-questions-about-larps-on-topic).

Escape puzzles would be **off topic** here, however. Most escape games do not have any roleplaying component (besides a very bare premise of "you must be a patient in this mental hospital" or "you must be a spy trying to ransack this room") - or really rules other than "solve puzzles and get out" - and therefore fall outside the fairly generous bounds of what an RPG is (like board games, computer RPGs, movie-marketing ARGs, etc.).

Comment: If an escape game *does* have a more developed roleplaying component and/or rules other than "solve puzzles and get out", does that make it a LARP? If not, then would a question about that game be on topic anyway? (Note: I am not aware of any such escape game's existence, but I'm curious where you would stand on that corner case.)