# Are questions related to building LARP safe weapons on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, larp

According to [Are questions about LARPs on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/165/10642) LARP questions are OK here, as LARP is a subset of role-playing games. But the question I want to ask is more about DIY techniques than the very act of role playing. I would ask it on a DIY stack, but sadly https://diy.stackexchange.com/ is now called Home Improvement and such questions would not be welcomed there.

---

Question I meant to add: *What are easy to apply latex alternatives on foam weapons?* with description of what do I hold against using latex.

Comment: Probably more relevant than DIY is [crafts.se] though I don't know whether they'd handle this. It being on topic on more than one site isn't a problem, though some sites dislike cross-posted questions.

Comment: I'll also offer just a brief concern around the proposed question as currently framed, it might run afoul of shopping, though that should be readily solved by focusing on how to get the same end result/properties without using latex.

Comment: @Someone_Evil I'd prefer LARPer answer than general artist answer anyway, so this one I'll ask here. Great to know Arts & Crafts exists for some of my other questions, even less connected to the larp world.

Answer (score 26):

#### We have handled such DIY questions for live action roleplaying, and should continue to do so.

We have several questions dealing with this topic, see the [props](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/props) tag. Here are a few examples:

- [How do I safely paint a latex-coated larp weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97024/how-do-i-safely-paint-a-latex-coated-larp-weapon)
- [LARP Cannon with actual projectiles](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77182/larp-cannon-with-actual-projectiles)
- [Is expanding foam a suitable material for LARP weapon construction?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59581/is-expanding-foam-a-suitable-material-for-larp-weapon-construction)
- [Are Polypropylene training weapons safe for LARP?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87185/are-polypropylene-training-weapons-safe-for-larp)
- [How do I patch up my weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12641/how-do-i-patch-up-my-weapon)

And for good measure, here is one that would probably fit at travel.se:

- [LARP Weapons on a Plane: Can you put your LARP sword in checked baggage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139544/larp-weapons-on-a-plane-can-you-put-your-larp-sword-in-checked-baggage)

The point is, these questions address a certain aspect of live action roleplaying that LARP experts are likely to have experience with. These experts will have better answers than generic DIY experts as LARP experts are more likely to have applied these DIY skills in the context you are asking about.

Comment: That's pretty much what I thought but I didn't want to be a judge in my own case, and wanted to be sure it's not just my wishful thinking.